# Do parenthesis force the content within to be executed first?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have multiple conditions in an if statement:

```
if x > 0.01 and x < 0.015 and y != 0 and (var_1 == var_2 == 0):
    #do...
```

Now from the reading i did, the parentheses will be executed first, am i correct in saying that? Secondly, are the parentheses in this example redundent if it does not matter that its checked first?

Comment: Please try to write your question's title to not just describe what topic your question is generally about, but to _actually ask the question_ (so someone can, from seeing the title alone, have a good idea about whether your question is the same as theirs, and whether your answers will help them). I'll try to edit towards that end. (If your question is too broad to summarize in a title, sometimes that means the question itself needs to be split into smaller ones to be on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chained comparisons in parentheses are equivalent to

```
(var_1 == var_2 and var_2 == 0)
```

So your whole expression is equivalent to

```
if x > 0.01 and x < 0.015 and y != 0 and (var_1 == var_2 and var_2 == 0):
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

The parentheses are redundant and the terms will still be evaluated left to right with short-circuiting.